# Refresh $scope variables from a service

Tags: angularjs

What is the proper method of refreshing data that is retrieved from a service? I am retrieving a test array from my `dataService` that I'd like to be automatically updated in my view when my `save()` method is called. I have commented the line that is supposed to update my $scope variable but yet nothing changes. Should I be wrapping it in $apply()?

The data that is placed into the array that `dataService.getActivities()` returns is from a cookie (which may or not be relevant).

```
app.controller("activityCtrl", ["$scope", "dataService", function ($scope, dataService) {

    $scope.newActivity = "";
    $scope.activities = dataService.getActivities();

    $scope.save = function (activity) {

        try{
            if (activity != "") {
                dataService.saveActivity(activity);

                $scope.newActivity = "";
                $scope.activities = dataService.getActivities(); //HERE
            }
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }        
    }
}
```

Here is my view, the array lives in a `ng-repeat`

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="activityCtrl">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <form novalidate>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Activity name" ng-model="newActivity" />
            <input type="submit" value="Add activity" ng-click="save(newActivity)" />
        </form>            
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-controller="activityCtrl">
        <div class="col-xs-2">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="activity in activities">
                <div class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{ active : activity.active }" ng-click="activate(activity)">{{ activity.name }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-left">
            sdfas
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

dataService code:

```
app.service("dataService", function () {

this.getActivities = function () {

    if (docCookies.hasItem("activities")) {

        var activities = JSON.parse(docCookies.getItem("activities"));

        if (activities.constructor != Array) {

            activities = [activities];
        }

        activities.sort(
            function (a, b) {
                if (a.name > b.name) { return 1; }
                if (b.name < a.name) { return -1; }
                return 0;
            });

        return activities;
    }

    return [];
}

this.saveActivity = function (activity) {

    if (!docCookies.hasItem("activities")) {

        docCookies.setItem("activities", [JSON.stringify({ "name": activity, "active": true })], Infinity);
    } else {

        var activities = this.getActivities();

        for (var i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {

            if (activities[i].name == activity) {
                throw "Activity already exists";
            }
        }

        activities.push({ "name": activity, "active": false });
        docCookies.setItem("activities", JSON.stringify(activities), Infinity);
    }

};
});
```

Comment: Can you show the dataService code? If its an async operation, you will need to wrap it in a `then()` statement from the promise

Comment: It does not use async operations, but I've copied it for reference

Comment: Try: **JS** - $scope.data = {}; ..... $scope.data.activities = dataService.getActivities(); **Markup** - <div class="row" ng-repeat="activity in data.activities">

Comment: No, that does not update the $scope variable.

Comment: probably a problem with getActivities / setActivities, are they returning anything (console.log it)

Comment: Console.log does indicate that the array is being updated

Comment: put a $scope.$apply() after the getActivities() call?

Comment: I wish that would work, but there was an error that an $apply was already in progress

Comment: What is docCookies? It appears to be global?

Comment: docCookies is the object from MDN's cookie library: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Answer (score 1):

Zac, your answer should work for you. As another option, I like to broadcast an event whenever my service is updated.  In the last line of your saveActivity() function in your service, try broadcasting an event on the rootScope. Inject the $rootScope into your service.  Add the following to your save method:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('activitiesUpdated');
```

Then in your controller, inject the $rootScope and add an event handler:

```
$rootScope.$on('activitiesUpdated', function(event, args){
     //Update $scope variable here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to look at the cookie value with a call to `$watch` instead of the method that returns an object. Added this in my `activityCtrl`

```
$scope.$watch(function () {

    return docCookies.getItem("activities");
}, function (oldVal, newVal) {

    $scope.activities = dataService.getActivities();
});
```